# Actionscript Commas

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this code and I want commas in my numbers. The jackpot is €169.85 but it is displayed as 16985 00 in the game. How to fix that?

```
public function jackpotstring():String {
    var myPattern:RegExp = /./; 
    var jp:Number = jackpot * denom;
    var s:String = jp.toFixed(2)+"";
    return s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-_:]+/g, ' ');
}
```

Comment: what is the "jackpot" variable's input value?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit clearer in explaining what you want to do. Are you trying to take an input of 1698500 and display it as 169.85?

Comment: What is the value of 'denom'?

Answer (score 0):

remove:

```
var s:String = jp.toFixed(2)+"";
```

change:

```
return s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-_:]+/g, ' ');
```

to:

```
return jp.toString().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-_:]+/g, ',');
```

Comment: Doesn't he still have to add `jp = jp.toString()` before the `return`?  That way it won't try to add commas into a Number

Comment: Yes he does Wobbuffet!  Good catch!  I edit my answer and you get a vote.  :)

Comment: Unfortunately, comment votes don't do anything helpful, except show people that it's important :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `, 2` and the empty string that you have in the second parameter in the execution of `replace`.  Try:

```
public function jackpotstring():String {
    var myPattern:RegExp = /./; 
    var jp:Number = jackpot * denom;
    var s:String = jp.toString();
    //                ^Change 1, a simple '.toString()' execution on 'jp'
    return s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-_:]+/g, ',');
    //                                       ^Change 2, added comma
}
```

[<kbd>Javascript converted Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/HVA3d/)